# Inference not working for generic methods

Tags: generics, dart

I have this generic method of a class:

```dart
StreamSubscription<T> each<T extends Object>(Stream<T> stream,
      void Function(T) fn,
      {Symbol uniqueId});
```

When I use it the argument for `fn` is dynamic:

```dart
Stream<String> stream;
each(stream, ((item) {})); // item here is dynamic. 

// I have to manually tell the type:
each<String>();

// or
each(stream, ((String item) {}));
```

it should be at least `Object` since `T` is expected to *extend* `Object`, right?

I've tested on nullsafety dartpad version and the difference is that the argument of `fn` is now `Object?` instead of dynamic. I think it is probably another inference error because the argument of `fn` is `T` and not `T?`.

Answer (score 1):

The way Dart generic function type argument inference works, it checks each argument independently, then tries to combine that to a type argument matching all of them.

In this case, `each(stream, (item) {})` has no type argument and no context type (so there are no constraints based on the return type), so the inference algorithm finds the static type of each argument *without knowing `T`*.

The static type of `stream` is `Stream<String>`.
The static type of `(item) {}` is `void Function(dynamic)`.

Then it tries to find a type `T` so that `Stream<String>` is a `Stream<T>` and `void Function(dynamic)` is a `void Function(T)`. Any type between `String` and `Object` (which includes `dynamic` pre-null-safety) can be used, because of the contravariance of function type parameters. Dart chooses `String`, which is a valid choice satisfied by both arguments, but the type of the function literal doesn't change, it stays `void Function(dynamic)`.

What you seem to be expecting is that the first argument, `stream`, is used to derive `T` = `String`, and then that `String` is used to infer the function is `void Function(String)`. That's not how it works, though, the second argument's type is found without any input from the first argument's type (and vice versa).

In null-safe mode, the parameter type of the function defaults to `Object?` instead of `dynamic`, but a `void Function(Object?)` is still a valid `void Function(String)`.

Comment: is there any plans to change this behavior? If not, why? I can read an issue to understand it better.