# How to have Dart infer Widget Generic Type based on property defined as same type?

Tags: dart

Say I have the following:

```
class SomeObject<TModel> extends StatelessWidget {
  final TModel someModel;
  final Widget Function(TModel model) builder;
  SomeObject({required this.someModel, required this.builder});
}
```

and I use this like this:

```
return SomeObject(someModel: SomeModel(), builder: (model) => {do something});
```

What I'm seeing is that SomeObject doesn't get the type of TModel inferred by SomeModel() setting someModel as I would see automatically happen in C# and thus builder: (model) is Object? instead of the correct type of someModel

How does one annotate to get dart to know that someModel being set defines the overall type of TModel for all of SomeObject and thus assign the builder: (model) to the right SomeObject automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure why the type cannot be inferred automatically, tough you might try to specify the type manually: `SomeObject<SomeModel>(...)`.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but it violates DRY.

Answer (score 0):

(I am not an expert on how Dart's type inference system works, so this is an educated guess.)

Given:

```dart
var object = SomeObject(someModel: SomeModel(), builder: (model) => ...);
```

`SomeObject`'s type parameter isn't specified, so it must be inferred *from* its arguments.  Its argument types are `SomeModel` and `Function(Object)`.  Should `SomeObject` be inferred from the `someModel` argument to be `SomeObject<SomeModel>`, or should it be inferred from the `builder` argument to be `SomeObject<Object>`?  Both seem equally valid.

For the `builder` argument to be inferred as `Function(SomeModel)`, inference would need to flow from the `someModel` argument out to the construction of `SomeObject` and then back down to the `builder` argument. [Dart argument type inference doesn't work that way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63966151/).

Additionally, since your problematic line is specifically a `return` statement, I suspect that the function it's from looks like:

```dart
SomeObject someFunction() {
  return SomeObject(someModel: SomeModel(), builder: (model) => ...);
}
```

If so, you should be aware that the `SomeObject` return type without an explicit type parameter is shorthand for `SomeObject<dynamic>`<sup>1</sup>.  Inference then will flow from the return type to the returned object, making it the equivalent of `return SomeObject<dynamic>(...)`.  To fix this, you should explicitly specify the return type to be `SomeObject<SomeModel>`, which should cause type inference to flow *to* the construction arguments and fix your problem.

Incidentally, you also should specify a return type for `Function(TModel model) builder;` declaration.

---

<sup>1</sup> This can be caught by the Dart analyzer by setting `strict-raw-types: true` in `analysis_options.yaml`.  See https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/resources/type-system/strict-raw-types.md for more details.

Comment: Everything is strongly typed in my case. I've updated the question to make that clear.  But the problem still remains. In every other language I've ever used that has generics it would a. enforce that all of the types of TModel anywhere in the signature were the same and b. use whatever ones are actually set to a type to infer the type. Dart doesn't seem to be doing that and I was wondering if there was some sort of meta package thing or something?

Comment: I'm not seeing your edit.  If your function is declared to return `SomeObject<SomeModel>`, then I do not believe that you should get an error. (I don't when I try it.) Please post a  reproducible example.

Comment: It returns Widget. Sorry. Forgot to actually update it.

Comment: I don't mean the return type of your `builder` function, I mean the declared return type of whatever function has `return SomeObject(...);`.

Comment: It's a stateless widget. The build method calls the builder function and returns the widget from that.  Think of this like StreamBuilder on steroids.

Comment: I'm assuming that the function where you use `SomeObject` is `Widget build(BuildContext context) { return SomeObject(...); }`?  As I said, if you change the return type to `SomeObject<SomeModel>`, the problem should go away.  Or using `return SomeObject<SomeModel>(...)` also would work in that case.  I'm not sure how C# or other languages resolve the ambiguity I described; how do they know which argument to infer from?

Comment: At any rate, regarding your question about annotations: annotations cannot help you.  Dart annotations don't *do* anything; they only provide hints to the analyzer (or other tools), and the inability to make the desired inference of the `builder` argument when inferring bottom-up isn't a problem with the analyzer.

Comment: C# infers from ALL arguments.  I tried this very example in C#, and it did it no problem at all. All TModel references must agree or rely on the TModel definition. I.e. the function (Func) receives TModel from the definition of the property because it's late bound and any implementation that diagrees throws an compile time error. Which is what I'd expect for Dart too.

Comment: To be clear, in the situation I describe, all definitions to `TModel` *do* agree in Dart too; it's just that there are two valid, competing definitions (`TModel` either can be `SomeModel` or `Object`.) And Dart *does* manage to choose `SomeObject<SomeModel>` (which is evident if the `builder` callback is modified to not access its argument); it's just that when doing bottom-up inference, nothing is known about the arguments, so I presume that `(model) => ...` is assumed to be `(Object? model) => ...`, and then its body is evaluated in that context.

Comment: Since C# apparently can deal with it better, I encourage you to file a bug at https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues. (If nothing else you will get an authoritative answer about how inference works in this case.)