# Dart (Flutter) Generic Type mismatch

Tags: flutter, dart

I have declared a generic Class with a generic typedef function:

Typedef:

```
typedef OnValueChanged<T> = void Function<T>(T);
```

Class:

```
class Increment<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final T maxValue;
  final T minValue;
  final T value;
  final T step;
  final Widget? display;
  final OnValueChanged<T> onValueChanged;
  final T? jumpStep;
  final bool active;

  Increment(
      {Key? key,
      required this.maxValue,
      required this.minValue,
      required this.value,
      required this.step,
      this.display,
      this.jumpStep,
      this.active = true,
      required this.onValueChanged})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _IncrementState createState() => _IncrementState<T>();
}

class _IncrementState<T> extends State<Increment> {
  static const Duration _skDefaultLongPressTriggerDuration =
      Duration(milliseconds: 100);

  Timer? _longPressTimer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isMinusEnabled = widget.active && widget.value - widget.step >= widget.minValue;
    bool isPlusEnabled = widget.active && widget.value + widget.step <= widget.maxValue;

    bool isJumpMinusEnabled = widget.jumpStep != null
        ? widget.active && widget.value - widget.jumpStep >= widget.minValue
        : false;
    bool isJumpPlusEnabled = widget.jumpStep != null
        ? widget.active && widget.value + widget.jumpStep <= widget.maxValue
        : false;
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.horizontal_rule,
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(isMinusEnabled ? 1 : 0.5),
          ),
          onTap: isMinusEnabled
              ? () => widget.onValueChanged(widget.value - widget.step)
              : null,
          onLongPressStart: (_) => widget.jumpStep != null
              ? isJumpMinusEnabled
                  ? () => setState(() {
                        onLongPress(-widget.jumpStep);
                      })
                  : null
              : null,
          onLongPressEnd: (_) => setState(
            () => _longPressTimer?.cancel(),
          ),
        ),
        widget.display != null ? widget.display! : Text("${widget.value}"),
        GestureDetector(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.add,
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(isPlusEnabled ? 1 : 0.5),
          ),
          onTap: isPlusEnabled
              ? () => widget.onValueChanged(widget.value + widget.step)
              : null,
          onLongPressStart: (_) => widget.jumpStep != null
              ? isJumpPlusEnabled
                  ? () => setState(() {
                        onLongPress(widget.jumpStep);
                      })
                  : null
              : null,
          onLongPressEnd: (_) => setState(() {
            _longPressTimer?.cancel();
          }),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void onLongPress(T longPressAmount) {
    _longPressTimer =
        Timer.periodic(_skDefaultLongPressTriggerDuration, (timer) {
      widget.onValueChanged(widget.value + longPressAmount);
    });
  }
}
```

Now when i want to provide this **OnValueChanged** Callback with a specified generic, like so:

```
Duration _betweenExercisesPauseDuration = Duration.zero;
...
Increment(
              minValue: Duration.zero,
              maxValue: Duration(hours: 23, minutes: 59, seconds: 59),
              step: Duration(seconds: 5),
              value: _betweenExercisesPauseDuration,
              display: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () async {
                    var result = await showDurationPickerInternal(
                        context, _betweenExercisesPauseDuration);
                    if (result != null) {
                      setState(() => _betweenExercisesPauseDuration = result);
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text(
                      "${NUMBER_FORMAT.format(_betweenExercisesPauseDuration.inHours)}h:${NUMBER_FORMAT.format(_betweenExercisesPauseDuration.inMinutes % 60)}m:${NUMBER_FORMAT.format(_betweenExercisesPauseDuration.inSeconds % 60)}s")),
              onValueChanged: <Duration>(Duration value) =>
                  setState(() {
                    _betweenExercisesPauseDuration = value;
                  }),
            )
```

I get an error from the Dart compiler:

```
A value of type 'Duration' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Duration'.
```

And it is pointing on *value*

This error does not occurr depandable, and i cannot imagine in other places why it works.
(I'm also using this Increment-Widget in other places with int, double and also Duration and it works. I think it's because i use the value passed by the function to set a field that is also defined to be of a generic type).

Should this be intendet as a bug from the compiler or i'm not understanding the concepts of generics in Dart?

My Setup:

```
Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 11.5.2 20G95 darwin-x64, locale de-DE)
environment sdk (in Pubspec.yaml): ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: `<Duration>(Duration value) => ...` creates a generic anonymous function with a type parameter named `Duration`.  If you want that anonymous function to take a `Duration` object as an argument, then use just `(Duration value) => ...`.

Comment: If i do not use the generic type parameter i get the error following error if the callback is invoked: ```type '(Duration) => void' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => void'```

Comment: Sorry, you also need to fix your `typedef`.  It should be just: `typedef OnValueChanged<T> = void Function(T);`.  By using `void Function<T>(T)`, you incorrectly made `OnValueChanged<T>` a generic `typedef` to a *generic* function that is parameterized on a different `T`.

Comment: It was alright your answer, i had to remove the <T> otherwise the compiler is complaining. So with ```typedef OnValueChanged<T> = void Function(T);``` the error i have postet before is occuring.

Comment: Did you remove *both* the extra `<T>` and the `<Duration>`?

Comment: Exactly after refactoring it was ```typedef OnValueChanged<T> = void Function(T);```and ```onValueChanged: (value) => {...})``` i get no compile errors, but on runtime ```type '(Duration) => void' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => void'```. But if i get completly rid of all generic types (e.g. Increment(...), (value) => ..., and so on) and let infer the type at runtime and also cast **value** to **Duration**, it works. Is this the way Dart works? Because so i don't have compile time type checking.

Comment: You removed the explicit parameter type for your anonymous function.  Without that, you're expecting that `(value) =>  ... ` be inferred as `void Function(Duration)` from a sibling argument, but Dart cannot infer function arguments from other arguments. You either must use an explicit parameter type (`(Duration value) => ...`) or explicitly use `Increment<Duration>`.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/63961561/ and https://stackoverflow.com/q/66711912/.