# Why does the identity function break type inference of function composition in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function that composes 3 functions while preserving type inference. Notice that my composition function is left-associative, so the functions are applied left to right.

```dart
D Function(A) compose3<A, B, C, D>(
        B Function(A) fa, C Function(B) fb, D Function(C) fc) =>
    (x) => fc(fb(fa(x)));

int incr(int x) => x + 1;

T id<T>(T x) => x;
```

The following code works as expected. The type of `res` is correctly inferred to be `int`.

```dart
void main() {
  var res = compose3(incr, incr, incr)(7);
  print('$res, ${res.runtimeType}'); // 10, int
}
```

However, after inserting the `id` function in the middle, the code does not compile.

```dart
var res = compose3(incr, id, incr)(7); // error
```

There are two errors:

```
Couldn't infer type parameter 'C'.

Tried to infer 'dynamic' for 'C' which doesn't work:
  Parameter 'fc' declared as     'D Function(C)'
                 but argument is 'int Function(int)'.
The type 'dynamic' was inferred from:
  Parameter 'fb' declared as     'C Function(B)'
                 but argument is 'dynamic Function(dynamic)'.

Consider passing explicit type argument(s) to the generic.
```

and

```
The argument type 'int Function(int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int Function(dynamic)'.
```

I have tried explicitly specifying the return type, but it didn't help.

```dart
int res = compose3(incr, id, incr)(7); // error
```

The following makes the errors go away, but it defeats the purpose of the `id` function.

```dart
T id<T extends int>(T x) => x;
```

Also, explicitly applying the functions works.

```dart
void main() {
  var res = incr(id(incr(7)));
  print('$res, ${res.runtimeType}'); // 9, int
}
```

This has been tested in Dartpad with null safety, Dart SDK 2.14.3.

Why does the `id` function break type inference in function composition and how can I make it work as expected?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63966151/.  `id` is given no explicit type, its type parameter will not be inferred sideways from other arguments, and therefore it will end up being `id<dynamic>`.

Comment: @jamesdlin it seems you are correct. However, that's not the desired or expected behavior. Are you saying that what I'm trying to do is currently impossible in Dart? Or is there some way to make it work, perhaps with a typedef?

Comment: It's not possible for the generic type of `id` to be inferred; you need to explicitly use `id<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using an extension method.

```
extension ComposeExtension on Function {
  C Function(A) pipe<A, B, C>(C Function(B) f) => (x) => f(this(x));
}

int incr(int x) => x + 1;

T id<T>(T x) => x;

void main() {
  var res = incr
    .pipe(id)
    .pipe(incr)(7);
  
  print('$res, ${res.runtimeType}'); // 9, int
}
```